# Income and expenditure problem

Tags: statistics, optimization, maxima-minima, economics, ratio

The ratio of income of Anun and Hanun is 7 and 9. While the saving ratio of both is $4000$ and $6000$. If the expenditure of A is 83.3% of B then what is the total income of both.
Here i am try by different method ,first I take $x$ is the income and y is the expenditure but i am stuck on last because i have one equation and there are two variables. please guide me ,

Comment: What do you mean by saving ratio? The standard definition for your figures would mean that Anun saves 4000 times his income.

Comment: Do you simply mean Anun saves $2/3$ of the amount that Hanun saves?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that

The incomes are respectively $7N$ and $9N$

The savings are $4000$ and $6000$.

Then $(7N-4000):(9N-6000)=5:6$.

The solution is then $N=2000$ and the total income is $32000$ units.

Comment: but in question saving ratio given not just ratio, secondly  where you bring 5:6

Comment: $5/6$ is $83.33 .. %$. As in my comments 'savings ratio' does not make sense in this context. To answer the question the amounts must be the actual savings.